# Angular ng-bind Not Updating Live

Tags: angularjs

I tried implementing $scope.$apply() but every way I tried it threw the error that $apply was already in progress. The ng-bind="controller.data.name is what I'm trying to update, but it only works on refresh. My understanding is that $http already calls $scope.$apply(), so I'm having a hard time conceptualizing why this isn't working.

Update: every piece of documentation I'm coming across shows that this code should be correct, yet the view will just not update.

index.html:

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="wishingWell">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport"
          content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/normalize.css">



    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular-route.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.js"   integrity="sha256-16cdPddA6VdVInumRGo6IbivbERE8p7CQR3HzTBuELA="   crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="/javascript/app.js"></script>

    <title>Wishing Well</title>
</head>

<body>
        <nav class="nav" ng-controller="home as controller">
            <ul class="navback">
                <li>
                    <a class="active" href="#/">The Well</a>
                </li>
                <li ng-hide="!authenticated">
                    <a href="#/profile" >Profile</a>
                </li>
                <li ng-hide="authenticated">
                    <a href="#/sign-up">Sign Up</a>
                </li>
                <li ng-hide="authenticated">
                    <a href="#/login">Log In</a>
                </li>
                <li ng-hide="!authenticated">
                    <a href="" ng-click="controller.logout()">Sign Out</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <span ng-bind="controller.data.name"></span>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>

        <div ng-view></div>

        <script src="/javascript/wishAJAX.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

app.js:

```
var wishingWell = angular.module('wishingWell', [ 'ngRoute' ]);

wishingWell.config(function($routeProvider, $httpProvider) {

    $routeProvider.when('/', {
        templateUrl : 'home.html',
        controller : 'home',
        controllerAs: 'controller'
    }).when('/login', {
        templateUrl : 'login.html',
        controller : 'navigation',
        controllerAs: 'controller'
    }).when('/sign-up', {
        templateUrl : 'sign-up.html',
        controller : 'register',
        controllerAs: 'controller'
    }).otherwise('/');

    $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common["X-Requested-With"] = 'XMLHttpRequest';

});

  wishingWell.controller('home', function($rootScope, $http, $location) {
    var jsonResponse;
    var jsonString;
    var self = this;
    self.data = {};

    $http.get('user2').then(function(response) {
        jsonString = JSON.stringify(response.data);
        jsonResponse = JSON.parse(jsonString);

        self.data.name = jsonResponse.msg;
    });


    self.logout = function() {
        $http.post('logout',{}).finally(function() {
            $rootScope.authenticated = false;
            $location.path("/");
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Why do you need `$scope.apply()` in your code? What does not work without it?

Comment: The GET request to 'user2' works and updates the model, but the ng-bind does not update the html view without refreshing the page.

Comment: what version of angular is it?

Comment: The version is 1.5.8.

Comment: should work fine....assuming the request completes properly. Also get rid of the `JSON.stringify()` and `JSON.parse()` it is completely redundant and end result it does nothing. Add some error handling

Comment: show your data structure

Comment: use $evalAsync instead of $apply.

Comment: Does it matter that I'm defining the controller twice, once in the nav element, and then also in the injected ng-view?

Comment: Anyone have an idea? This should work no problem, but I'm just banging my head against the wall trying to figure out why it isn't.

Comment: there definitely are two instances of the controller here.  It's not a good practice to use the same controller function for both `ng-controller` and a route `controller:`.  Changes to one instance will not be reflected in the other instance.  Without setting up a sample and tracing the execution, it's hard to know for sure if this is what is causing your problem, but it is very likely that somehow having two instances of the controller is breaking the bindings.

Comment: my *supposition* on the matter is that the alias `self` that you are creating in the controller is being changed to the other instance when it initializes, and this is causing the `$http` to be updating the *other* instance properties.  reloading causes the controllers to be processed again, and the code magically switches to the right instance for a moment, before being directed back to the other right after, and voila, your bindings show the data loaded on the previous iteration.

Comment: Thanks for your input. I will work on separating these controllers and see how the results differ.